# Where is the CD / DVD Burner application

Tags: nautilus, dvd, cd

Inserting a blank dvd does not pop up the autoplay.
Search in dash or ubuntu software centre does not match anything called CD / DVD Creator.

I tried Brasero but it crashes.

I'm just trying to burn an .avi file

Here it is on the web

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/nautilus-cd-burner/

but can't find it on my system.

Windows burned the disk fine.  Back in Ubuntu I can use the Send To method and this time when I insert the blank disc I get "Unable to mount blank DVD R disk, location is already mounted" error and a DVDR icon in the launcher.  Ignoring the error I can get to the CD/DVD Creator... and it works now?!  Thanks for your help still not sure why it's so temperamental.

Comment: Does the blank dvd's and cd's work in windows

Comment: http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/03/9-good-cd-and-dvd-burning-tools-for.html lists GnomeBaker, k3b and other burner apps.  You may consider one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The way i use the nautilus cd/dvd burner is quite easy.

- Select files and folders that you want to write to disc in nautilus.
- Right-click those selected files/folders to get the context menu to appear.
- In the contextual menu choose "Send to... " .
- When the "Send to.." box appears,choose "cd/dvd creator" as the destination.
- Also choose new cd/dvd right below and remove the check from the compression checkbox.
- Press the send button.
- You will now see a new window with the selected items, you can change the title and add or remove items to write to disc.
- When you are ready to write the disc, just press write to disc button.

Comment: @leep does this answer work for your situation ?